# Flash plugin keeps crashing in Opera 12

Tags: windows-8.1, flash, opera

I recently installed my Windows 8.1 and Opera 12.17, and
also installed 64-bit version of Flash player.

When I open heavy Flash-using sites, I always get this message:

```
Opera Crash Logging
---------------------------
Crash log writing failed, error creating crashlog event!
Error description from system: The operation finished successfully.
```

In the event viewer, I have this message:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-01-13T16:26:25.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>1706</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>PC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>opera_plugin_wrapper.exe</Data> 
  <Data>12.17.1863.0</Data> 
  <Data>534cfe97</Data> 
  <Data>NPSWF64_16_0_0_240.dll</Data> 
  <Data>16.0.0.240</Data> 
  <Data>547e7847</Data> 
  <Data>c0000005</Data> 
  <Data>0000000000001aeb</Data> 
  <Data>1278</Data> 
  <Data>01d02f4910f79bf7</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Program Files\Opera x64\pluginwrapper\opera_plugin_wrapper.exe</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF64_16_0_0_240.dll</Data> 
  <Data>ea8b111c-9b40-11e4-825b-902b346126e3</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you really need flash? I uninstalled half a year ago and have no problems :)

Comment: My Opera is this: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.17. If I use 32-bit Flash, it also crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the *64-bit version of Opera* is **unstable** and it makes the Flash plugin crash.

I have installed the 32-bit version of Opera and Flash works okay.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Flash from your computer then re-install it from a Firefox 32bit-version.

Comment: How does it help my Opera?